# How to generate a certain type of diagram from another type in EA?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I'm stiil a newbie with Enterprise Architect. I was wondering is there a way to generate automatically a certain type of diagram from an already existing other type of diagram and if yes - between what types of diagrams it could be achieved.

For example, could a sequence diagram be generated out of a given class diagram? Or it isn't possible because the sequence diagrams are behavioral and the class diagrams are structural?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Yes**, you can generate **some** diagrams, e.g. if you have a structured use case scenario then see http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/modeling_basics/generate_diagrams.html. But your structural vs behavioral note is good point, so what exactly is the problem that you want to solve automatically?

Answer (score 2):

To concrete Vladimir's answer: a diagram is not a model. If you want to transform anything you need to focus on packages (single elements would not make much sense anyway).

Answer (score 1):

it is absolutely not possible transform or generate class diagram to (from) sequence because of different semantic of diagrams. It is not good idea to do any transformation between diagram definitions. If some tool allows it, it always directed to a meaningless or incomplete structures.